# Programmimg Logic

Tags: php, logic

Am new to the world of coding and have difficulty is understanding the logic below. Appreciate it if someone could explain it to me. Let me start off with If statements.

/* Sample Code */

```
if($username == "123") {
//some code here;
}

if ($username == "abc") {
//some code here;
}
```

My understanding is that IF the first statement fails, progress to the second statement i.e. if $username does not equal to 123 then test whether it is abc. Is that correct?

Now, let me expand on that same code with else statements

/* Sample Code */

```
if($username == "123") {
//some code here;
}

if ($username == "abc") {
//some code here;
}

else {
//some code here;
}
```

My understanding is that IF the first staement FAILS i.e. $username does not equal to 123 then test the second statement. IF the second statement fails i.e. $username does not equal to abc then proceed to ELSE which is a catchall should all preceding IF statements FAIL. Is that correct?

Let me expand on that again using ELSE IF statements

/* Sample Code */

```
if($username == "123") {
//some code here;
}

else if ($username == "abc") {
//some code here;
}

else {
//some code here;
}
```

How is this code different from 2 separate if statements? What does ELSE do in the entire block of code?

Answer (score 3):

the difference between:

```
if() {

}
else if() {

}
```

and

```
if() {

}
if() {

}
```

is that the second condition in the second example is always tested, regardless of the first if condition.  In the first example, the second clause only executes if the first clause is false.

Comment: Great. That is so much clearer. How does ELSE fit into the equation in both examples?

Comment: If you add an else to the first example, it will execute if the if and else if both fail.  If you add an else to the second example, it will execute if the if clause you put it after fails

Comment: So to clarify.If I place an ELSE in the second example i.e.

if(){
}

if() {
}

else{
}

the first IF statement will execute if the condition is met and ELSE may also execute if the second condition fails. Is that right?

Comment: yes.  In that case the outcome of the first IF does not affect the else clause.  And if the second if evaluates to false, the else clause will be executed.  Exactly ! :D

Comment: Ok so I could have multiple ELSE statements for each of the IF statements e.g.

if() {
}

else {
}

if() {
}

else {
}

I suppose that in such an example it's probably better to have ELSE IF statements

Comment: Yes, you could do what you describe.  But in that case, each if statement still only has 1 else statement.  And you cannot capture the same scenario with an else if.

Comment: When you say the same scenario do you mean that if the first condition fails then execute the second condition? Why would I want to have the example if() { } else { } if() { } else { }?

Comment: what if you want to check on two things completely unrelated and for each case you have a fall back.  In that case you need an if/else if/else.  if/elseif/else does not give you the same thing.

Comment: Thanks.Can you give me an example of where I may want to use if/else if else?

Comment: if(today.equals("friday"){}else{} if(weather.equals("sunny")){}else{}...Basically anytime the two clauses are independent.  In this case the day of the week doesn't affect the weather, but we are interested in both things.

Comment: Righto. Think my confusion is clearing. Is there a way to decide when to use if/if/else and if/else if/else?

Comment: All depends on what you are trying to do in your program =]

Comment: So I take it there isn't a general rule of thumb?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, since "123" is never equal to "abc", they are equivalent.  In real life, the `if`s don't need to be related:

```
if (a) {
  // Do something
} else if (b) {
  // Do something else
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

is different from

```
if (a) {
  // Do something
}
if (b) {
  // Do something else
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

In the second case, both `a` and `b` might be true, in which case both lines will fire. In the first case, only the first line will fire, since the `else` will never even be read.

Comment: Thanks. So how do the ELSE statements work in both examples? The bit about IF and ELSE IF is much clearer however am still confused about ELSE

Comment: ELSE only executes when its related IF is false.  In the first example, the last ELSE is technically only related to the 2nd IF, if the first IF is true, the ELSE IF will not fire, and therefore the ELSE will not fire. In the second example, the last ELSE is related to the second IF, but not the first IF. So regardless of what happens to the first IF, the ELSE will fire if the second IF is not true.

Comment: So in the second example it could be that the first IF could fire together with ELSE assuming that the second IF is not true.

Comment: Yep, the first IF and the next IF are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

In this case they are the same:

```
if($username == "123") {
//some code here;
}

if ($username == "abc") {
//some code here;
}
```

against

```
if($username == "123") {
//some code here;
}

else if ($username == "abc") {
//some code here;
}
```

The difference is that with `else if` if the first case is true the second case will never fire.

e.g.

```
if($username == "123") {
//some code here;
    $username = "abc"
}

if ($username == "abc") {
//some code here;
}
```

Both code if statement code blocks will be executed where as in:

```
if($username == "123") {
//some code here;
    $username = "abc"
}

else if ($username == "abc") {
//some code here;
}
```

only the first if statement code block will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't right, here's how it works:

```
if($something == "something")
{
//code
}
if($something == "somethingelse")
{
//code
}
```

Both of the above will be tested regardless of what `$something` equals, because they are two separate if statements.  So if you were to do:

```
$something = "something";
if($something == "something")
{
     echo $something;
}
$something = "somethingelse";
if($something == "somethingelse")
{
    echo $something;
}
```

then the output would be "somethingsomethingelse" because both are tested.  Note that in an if/elseif/else structure, it would be a syntax error to put a line of code between the ending of one block and the beginning of another.

```
if($something == "something")
{
//code
}
else
{
//code
}
```

In this, the first statement will be tested, if it is true, then it will run through that code.  If false, then the code in the `else` block will occur.

```
if($something == "something")
{
//code
}
elseif($something == "somethingelse")
{
//code
}
else
{
//code
}
```

In this it would check the first if statement, if true, then that code runs.  If false, it checks the elseif statement, if true it runs that.  If false it runs the `else` block.  The `else` block is a catch all.

So in something like:

```
if(false)
{
//code
}
elseif(false)
{
//code
}
else
{
//code
}
```

the else block will always be run.

The same sort of thing occurs in multiconditional statements such as:

```
if(is_string($something) && $something == "something")
```

if `is_string($something)` is false, it won't check the second condition because they both must be true when AND is used, and if `is_string($something)` is true and `$something == "something"` is false, then the entire if condition is false, yet again because they both must be true.

```
if($something == "something" || $something == "somethingelse")
```

In this OR statement, it will check both if the first is false, because one or the other must be true in order for the if statement to be true.  So if `$something` does equal `"somethingelse"` then the if statement will be considered true.  However, if `$something` does equal `"something"` then the second condition won't be checked, because it already got the true condition it needs to make the statement true.

So an `&&` condition in an if condition is like doing:

```
if(is_string($something))
{
     if($something == "something")
     {
     //code
     }
}
```

and and `||` statement is like doing:

```
if($something == "something")
{
    //code
}
elseif($something == "somethingelse")
{
   //same code as previous if statement
}
```

Here is an example:

```
//this would be pulled from a page called like:
//http://www.domain.com/page.php?num=5&num2=10
$num = $_GET['num'];  //5
$num2 = $_GET['num2'];  //10

if(!is_numeric($num))
{
    echo 'Number 1 is not a number, cannot continue <br />';
}
elseif(!is_numeric($num2))
{
    echo 'Number 2 is not a number, cannot continue <br />';
}
else
{
     if($num > $num2)
     {
         echo 'Number 1 is bigger than Number 2 <br />';
     }
     elseif($num2 > $num)
     {
         echo 'Number 2 is bigger than Number 1 <br />';
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'Numbers are equal <br />';  
         //Since if the numbers are neither greater than or less than each other, they must be equal to one another
     }//end if

     //% is the modulo operator, basically returns the remainder of division
     //so !($num % $num2) is if the remainder of $num / $num2 == 0, I.E. NOT(!) $num % $num2
     //! basically makes it take the opposite of the result, so !(0) is true, and 0 is false
     //in the same way !(true) is literally NOT true (in other words false) 
     //and !(false) is literally NOT false (true) 
     if(!($num % $num2))  
     {
         echo 'Number 1 is a multiple of Number 2 <br />';
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'Number 1 is not a multiple of Number 2 <br />';
     }//end if

     if(!($num2 % $num))
     {
         echo 'Number 2 is a multiple of Number 1 <br />';
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'Number 2 is not a multiple of Number 1 <br />';
     }//end if

     echo 'The sum of the numbers is ' . $num + $num2;

}//end if
```

So, with this, and an input of num=5&num2=10, the output would be

```
Number 2 is bigger than Number 1
Number 1 is not a multiple of Number 2
Number 2 is a multiple of Number 1  //Note that both of the multiple conditions were tested, because they are separate
The sum of the numbers is 15
```

With this an an input of num=16&num2=3, the output would be:

```
Number 1 is bigger than Number 2
Number 1 is not a multiple of Number 2
Number 2 is not a multiple of Number 1
The sum of the numbers is 19
```

and with an input of num=16&num2=word, the only output would be

```
Number 2 is not a number, cannot continue
```

and with an input of num=4&num2=4 the output would be

```
Numbers are equal
Number 1 is a multiple of Number 2
Number 2 is a multiple of Number 1
The sum of the numbers is 8
```

Comment: Wow, that was quite the read but I think I get it. So in the scenario of using an ELSE statement, it is ALWAYS the catch-all. Is that safe to assume that?

Comment: Yes, it is always a catch all.  It's what is done if nothing else in the if/elseif structure is true.  You come to a four way intersection, if you're going to the grocery store then turn left, else if you are going to get your hair cut then go right, otherwise (else) keep on going straight.  Also, remember that you can only have one `if` at the top of an if/elseif/else structure, and you can only have one else at the end of it, but you can have as many elseifs as needed.  Now, you can have nested if/elseif/else where you put an if inside another if, like with the `&&` example above.

Comment: Thanks Phoenix. Joe Enos mentioned that an ELSE statement has a relationship with the preceding IF hence in the example below if the first condition is met but the second condition fails. the ELSE statment can still be true e.g.

if(true){
}

if(false){
}

else{ //true
}

Hopefully I have not confused myself.

Comment: Yes.  Sort of.  In your example the first if statement has nothing to do with the second if/else statement, they are completely separate, hence why the else in the second statement will run if the first is true and the second is false, because the first statement has absolutely no bearing on it.  It's a completely separate and self contained logic process and can have it's own elseifs and else.  Any time you use `if(something)` it's a totally new block of logic which can be extended by elseifs and an else.  Of course, they can be contained within other blocks of logic.

Comment: For instance `if(true){ if(false){}else{//this runs}//end nested if }//end original if`.  Perhaps it would be easier to understand if I used such notation with the example you gave: `if(true){}//end first if` `if(false){}else{//true} //end second if` the `}` closes the block, and if there isn't an elseif or else after it, then that's it for that `if`.  `elseif` and `else` are the only things that extend an `if` statement to check for more potential conditions (or catch all in the case of `else`), another `if` starts a whole new thing.

Comment: I'm going to update my answer right quick with a quick script to demonstrate in a potential application.

Comment: Alright, updated, feel free to copy/paste and run it somewhere and play with the code and test inputs and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that IF the first
>   statement fails, progress to the
>   second statement i.e. if $username
>   does not equal to 123 then test
>   whether it is abc. Is that correct?

This isn't correct. Both expressions will be evaluated; however, at most one of them can be true. Your third example behaves the way you describe above.

In your second example, if $username == "123", then the block associated with the first if statement will execute; however, the "else" block associated with the second if statement will also execute.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, both "if" statements are executed.  If both are true, both happen.

In your case, both can't be true, but that's no reason not to use "else".  If nothing else [no pun intended], "else" will provide a semantic hint for future programmers that you're only expecting one of the two clauses to be true.

The only way for your statement:

> IF the first statement fails, progress to the second statement

to be true is if the second statement was indeed in an "else" clause of the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

Only in the last snippet does the code behave as you describe. When you have an `if` followed by a second `if`, *both* tests are performed. There is no symbiosis or relation in the code flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(X1){
    A;
}elseif(X2){
    B;
}elseif(X3){
    C;
}else{
    D;
}
```

this means: if X1 evaulates to true then do A. If not look if X2 evaluates to true. if yes do B. if not look if X3 evaluates to true. if so do C. if not then just do D.

```
if(X1){
    A;
}


if(X2){
    B;
}
```

this means: if X1 evaluates to true do A. end of your first if. then another if comes: if X2 evaluates to true then do B. these two if statements are separated from eachother unlike my first example.

the alternative if syntax in php makes it a bit clearer:

My first example in alternative syntax:

```
if(X1):
    A;
elseif(X2):
    B;
elseif(X3):
    C;
else:
    D;
endif;
```

my second example:

```
if(X1):
    A;
endif;


if(X2):
    B;
endif;
```

here you see clearly that these two if statements are separated from eachother.

Comment: also try not to separate the else from the closing `}`

Comment: Thanks lTroubs. Didn't quite follow what you meant by "also try not to separate the else from the closing }"

Comment: if(X){dosomething;}else{dosomethingelse;} i for instance keep the `}else{` always in one line.